# MySql Duplicate a row and replace part of a field in the duplicate

Tags: mysql, replace, duplicates

I'm trying to duplicate a row in a mysql db and at the same time replace part of a string in one field of the duplicated row.

I've figured out how to:

1. duplicate a row

   ```
   INSERT INTO account_external_ids 
   SELECT * FROM account_external_ids 
   where external_id like '%gerrit:%';
   ```
2. do the replace of the string but cant figure out how to do both in the same query.

   ```
   UPDATE account_external_ids 
   SET external_id = REPLACE(external_id,'gerrit:','username:') 
   WHERE external_id like '%gerrit%';
   ```

But can't figure out how to do both in the same query, something like:

```
INSERT INTO account_external_id   
select * from account_external_ids 
set external_id = replace(external_id, 'gerrit:', 'username:') 
where external_id like '%gerrit%';
```

Any pointers would be great.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to list all the columns explicitly, you can't use `SELECT *` if you're modifying any of the columns

```
INSERT INTO account_external_id (col1, col2, col3, col4, external_id)
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, REPLACE(external_id, 'gerrit:', 'username:')
FROM account_external_ids
WHERE external_id LIKE '%gerritt:%'
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar that worked perfectly! Final query is:
    INSERT INTO account_external_ids (account_id, email_address, password, external_id)
SELECT account_id, email_address, password, REPLACE(external_id, 'gerrit:', 'username:')
FROM account_external_ids
WHERE external_id LIKE '%gerrit:%';